# Which hardware configuration is necessary for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, windows, system-requirements

What kind of hardware is necessary to run QGIS on Win XP?

#### Closely related:

[Specifications for GIS desktop hardware](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23300/specifications-for-gis-desktop-hardware)

Comment: I do a lot of my operation on RamDisk, as I found it very, very fast. Its expensive (RAM is more expensive than SSD) but I do think it is faster though.

Answer (score 3):

QGIS doesn't have formal ["system requirements" per-se](http://www.mail-archive.com/qgis-user@lists.osgeo.org/msg08446.html). However, this question has been discussed before, i.e.: [Specifications for GIS desktop hardware](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23300/specifications-for-gis-desktop-hardware)

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, for common applications any hardware would do the job, for example, I have and old notebook which runs Windows XP and Qgis nicely on 1GB RAM and a Centrino (Pentium-M) processor. 
As I always say, you won't need a lot of processing power to digitize vectors or interpret imagery, for that the best hardware to spend your money is a nice 21" led screen.
If you want to do some advanced processing with rasters (interpolations, etc.) you may want more memory and a better processor but be aware that most of these tasks don't take advantage of multicore cpus, so to have a real nice performance you will have to split the tasks and run many instances of whatever you want to process.