# Which Windows OS is supported?

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

Please can you tell me which Windows OS Quantum Desktop supports.

i.e. Windows 7, XP, Vista etc.

Answer (score 7):

All Windows operating systems (32-bit/64-bit) are supported by Quantum GIS. I could install QGIS on latest Windows 8.1 Preview too.

Comment: Anyone tested on Windows RT?

Comment: @Mapperz, you will find this [answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/68488/1217) interesting - QGIS on Windows Surface

Answer (score 1):

It works on XP, Vista, Windows 2003, Windows 7 and 8

Comment: Is there a link to those system requirements from the QGIS documentation that can be included?

Comment: Unfortunately not. At least, I couldn't find it.

Comment: @PolyGeo, looks like they don't publish formal hardware/software requirements. Came across this 2011 email on [QGIS user mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/qgis-user@lists.osgeo.org/msg08446.html) from this Stack GIS [answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/25178/1217)